# How to know http response end?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, twisted, httpresponse

When we enter a url and send it to http server from browser, we get the response from server sometimes a request **with multi http response for one url** , is there a way I can know which http response package is the **final one**?

I use `python twisted` to see the response header and I can't figure out the difference of first header and final header.

Comment: Do you mean the server returns  responses with 3xx http status code (redirection) and your software does not follow the redirection automatically? The redirection loop can be infinite.

Comment: no, just normal request, how browser know the whole page loaded? It's just because  current web page doesn't send further request?

Comment: All requests are sent by the user, so if all requests are answered, all requests are answered. If you transport html then you have to check on the html if it needs any more requests to "be complete".

Answer (score 8):

A HTTP response consists of *headers* followed by a message *body*.

The HTTP headers must all end with a `<CR><LF>` newline. The headers are followed by an *empty line* and then the [HTTP body data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_body_data).

The `Content-Length:` headers should specify the size of the message body *in bytes* so that the HTTP user-agent (or client) such as a browser knows how many bytes to read for body of the HTTP resource.

---

See the following links for more info:

- [HTTP/1.0, RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)
- [HTTP/1.1, RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)
- [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)